# How to make an alias in eshell

Tags: eshell, c

I want to make an alias in eshell so that when I type gcc it actually does `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99` but when I make the alias, it just displays `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99` and doesn't actually compile the program. Any ideas?

Comment: Show what you have tried, to help others help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eshell aliases `$*` is replaced by the list of arguments passed after the aliased command. (You can also use `$1` to get the first argument, `$2` for the second, etc.)

So, try

```
alias gcc "gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 \$*"
```

As far as I know this behavior is not documented in the manual. See the [EmacsWiki Eshell Alias](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias) page and the comment at the top of [`em-alias.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/eshell/em-alias.el), though.